# Error when adding resources params for connection to database

Tags: zend-framework, zend-server-ce

I'm adding this to application.ini into section production

```
resources.db.adapter           = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.dbname     = "rzeki"
resources.db.params.host       = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username   = "root"
resources.db.params.password   = ""
resources.db.params.charset    = "utf8"
```

but when i'm running aplication I've got this error:

```
    Stack trace:
#0 C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Config\Ini.php(296): Zend_Config_Ini->_processKey(Array, 'params.dbname', 'rzeki')
#1 C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Config\Ini.php(296): Zend_Config_Ini->_processKey(Array, 'db.params.dbnam...', 'rzeki')
#2 C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Config\Ini.php(261): Zend_Config_Ini->_processKey(Array, 'resources.db.pa...', 'rzeki')
#3 C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Config\Ini.php(153): Zend_Config_Ini->_processSection(Array, 'production')
#4 C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Application.php(386): Zend_Config_Ini->__construct('C:\Program File...', 'production') 
#5 C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\share\ in C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Config\Ini.php on line 294
```

I'm using Netbeans + ZendServer CE

Edit:

When I'm installing digitalous, main index.php in install folder :

> > Warning: include_once(Digitalus\Installer.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
> >     directory in C:\Program
> >     Files\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Loader.php on
> >     line 146
>
> Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   'Digitalus\Installer.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.;./library;.;C:\Program
>   Files\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library') in C:\Program
>   Files\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Loader.php on
>   line 146
>
> Fatal error: Class 'Digitalus_Installer' not found in C:\Program
>   Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\digitalus\install\install.php on line 19

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! There seems to be an issue with the dbname-parameter. Are you sure that's what it's called? According to this - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.adapters.ini.html - there seems to be a discrepancy between parameter-names. =)

Comment: the syntaxes seems correct to me, are you sure you are defining the correct username/password/dbname parameter?, not sure but the issue seems like to be with dbname value. do you have already existing database with name `rzeki`

Comment: @J.Steen, he have the syntax defined correctly, resources. are prefixed to tell zend framework to automatically parse the value.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar Fair enough. =)

Comment: @user1547931 have you granted the privileges to the database?

Comment: Yes. I've got privilages